# Cant inherit TestCase from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, inheritance

im using the unittest Framework to test my flask application. Since i have multiple Testcase classes i want to structure/refactor them.

> BaseTest.py contains:

```
import unittest
from config import Config
from app import create_app, db

class TestConfig(Config):
    """ overridden config for testing """

class TestInit(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(TestConfig)
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        self.app = self.app.test_client()
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()
```

Then i try to have testcases in

> ProjectTest.py:

```
from app.models import *
from tests.BaseTest import TestInit


class ProjectTest(TestInit):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        # create Test Data
        proj1 = Project(
            name='TestProject1',
            project_state_id=1,
            project_type_id=1
        )
        db.session.add(proj1)
        db.session.commit()
        for pro in Project.query.all():
            print(pro)

    def test_project_add(self):
        pass
```

i get the error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.BaseTest'; 'tests' is not a package

I have all theses files in the folder `tests` and tried all variation on how to import it (even with a `__init__.py` file) but i always get the error.

Answer (score 1):

if your source codes are in the same folder, you don't need to import `tests.BaseTest`
because interpreter shouldn't look anywhere else except current folder.

just importing `BaseTest` would be enough.

edited code would be:

```py
from BaseTest import TestInit
```